# WiX undefined preprocessor variable

Tags: wix, preprocessor, build-automation, wix3, votive

I'm starting to use WiX in order to do automated builds to create msi's of my c# projects and am experiencing the error **"Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)'"**

I am using the latest WiX v3.0.5419. Inside my wxs file I am trying to use pre-processor variables that are listed on this webpage ([**http://blogs.msdn.com/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx**](http://blogs.msdn.com/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx))

```
<Component Id="MyId" Guid="MyGuid">
   <File Id="MyId" Name="MyName" KeyPath="yes" 
      Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)\MyName.dll" />
</Component>
```

I have added the reference for MyProject to the .wixproj and if I open it up in Notepad I can see the reference.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.csproj">
    <Name>MyProject</Name>
    <Project>{guid}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is my nant build script that I use to create the msi. Maybe it's because the .wixproj knows about the project reference which isn't used in the build?

```
<exec basedir="${tools.wix}" managed="true" program="candle.exe">
  <arg line='-out "${tools.wix.objfile}"' />
  <arg value="../MySetup.wxs" />
</exec>
```

Can anyone enlighten me on this please?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As you already remarked, your nant build script is not using the `wixproj` file at all.

You are mixing two different ways to build a wix setup here:

1. You can use the `candle.exe` and `light.exe` command line tools directly. This ignores the `.wixproj` file. This is what you are doing in your nant build script. To pass values for preprocessor variables like `$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)`, use options like `-dMyProject.TargetDir=c:\foo`.
2. You can author a .wixproj file with votive (the visual studio add-on for wix). Like all visual studio project files, a wixproj file is actually a msbuild file which can be build with `msbuild.exe`. Variables like `$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)` are automatically set by the msbuild tasks for building wix setups if the correct project reference exists.

I recommend you build the wixproj file with the `<msbuild>` [nant task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html). This ensures that your nant build does the same as when you build the setup manually from visual studio.

Comment: Thanks very much. I just found out that the wixproj is a msbuild file and I was actually already building it correctly through building my solution!

Comment: Just as a quick heads up -- The correct way to specify the option would be -dMyProject.TargetDir. The leading var. is erroneous.

http://geekswithblogs.net/Howard/archive/2009/01/20/wix-variables.aspx

Comment: Every time I use WIX I forget about how preprocessor variables have to be declared on the command line.  Thanks man!

Comment: I was trying to build a simple installer to start working with WiX by following **[these](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)** instructions. As a result, I am getting the "Undefined preproc var `$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)`" error. I tried to add in the Build props `var.myApplication.TargetPath=D:\Apps;` but the error remained. Can you help? I am missing something in the answer ... the var seems to be correct (see **[this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jrock/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables/)** list).

Comment: @Matt You need to add reference to the project you are trying to install.

Comment: "If the correct reference exists" Thank you very much.