# Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.WixInstall.TargetPath)'. WixInstaller D:work\Extractor\WixInstaller\Product.wxs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix

I'm facing the following error while create windows installer using wix.
Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.WixInstall.TargetPath)'. WixInstaller    D:\work\Extractor\WixInstaller\Product.wxs

Please Note: I have tried the following answers but no gain
[[Wix 'undefined preprocessor variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784833/wix-undefined-preprocessor-variable]) , 
[[WiX undefined preprocessor variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063630/wix-undefined-preprocessor-variable]) , 
[[WiX - Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.SetupProject1.TargetDir)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995549/wix-undefined-preprocessor-variable-var-setupproject1-targetdir])

Product.wxs code

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="WixInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixInstaller" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixInstaller" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
             <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="$(var.WixInstall.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Getting a Heartbeat***: First things first: get your source to compile so you can check if there are other problems:

1. ***Absolute Path***: Please try to hard code a full path to a file that you know exists at the target location:

   ```
    <File Source="D:\My Files\MyBinary.exe" />
   ```
2. ***Manufacturer***: Next set the **`"Manufacturer" attribute`** to something. Anything will do so long as there is something there. Put your company name - obviously.

=> Try to compile. This should succeed.

---

***Missing Definition***: OK, with a heartbeat going, let's try to solve the problem. Where are you getting this pre-processor construct from:

```
<File Source="$(var.WixInstall.TargetPath)" />
```

Is this from some sample or something? I assume **`"WixInstall"`** is referring to the WiX project itself inside the Visual Studio solution? Generally you can refer to projects inside your solution like this - by name - but normally you refer to another project, such as "MyBinaryProject" and you refer to its build output like this:

```
<File Source="$(var.MyBinaryProject.TargetPath)" />
```

You need to make sure the project you refer to is actually in the Visual Studio solution. And you need to add a reference to it:

1. Right click **`"References"`** in your WiX project => **`Add Reference...`**
2. Under **`"Projects"`** select the project you want to refer to, press **`Add`** and **`OK`**.

---

***WiX Documentation***: [Using Project References and Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) - please see that WiX documentation entry for details on the built-in variables available when you have referenced other Visual Studio projects.

---

***Regular Preprocessor Variable***: Besides the built-in preprocessor variable you get when you add a reference to another Visual Studio project, you can also define your own variables:

```
<?define MyTest= "D:\My Files\MyBinary.exe" ?>
<...>
<File Source="$(var.MyTest)" />
```

---

***Links***:

- More on advanced pre-processor features and other things: [Wix Installer : Setting component condition property when doing a MSIEXEC admin install at command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449985/wix-installer-setting-component-condition-property-when-doing-a-msiexec-admin/49501700#49501700)
- On different variable types in WiX:  [WiX (Windows Installer Xml), Create universal variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444241/wix-windows-installer-xml-create-universal-variables/50452114#50452114)
- [WiX quick start short version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305272/adventures-in-installing-a-c-wpf-application-wix/63308043#63308043)
- [WiX quick start very long version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

Comment: Seems to be a comprehensive answer. I will try and get back here.

Answer (score 0):

That code references a project called WiXInstall in your solution.

I recommend looking at: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials